# Index intersection between multi-key index and text index in MongoDB 2.6

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

My schema looks something like:

```
{
    concepts: [
        {name:..., word:..., start:..., stop:...}
    ],
    text:...
}
```

I have a text index on the "text" field and a multi-key index on "concepts.name":

```
db.col.ensureIndex({text:"text"})
db.col.ensureIndex({"concepts.name":1})
```

When I run:

```
db.col.find({"concepts.name":"something"})
```

I get 10 results and 10 scans. But when I run:

```
db.col.find({"concepts.name":"something",$text:{$search:"querystring"}}):
```

I get less results but it takes longer and scans a much larger number of documents. I was expecting that the new index intersection feature of MongoDB 2.6 would automatically first cut it down to 10 documents and then do the text search on those. What am I missing? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a compound index to support that query. MongoDB 2.6 Index intersection does not work with text indexes. There's an example [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/limit-number-of-items-scanned-for-text-search/) in the documentation.

```
db.col.ensureIndex({"concepts.name": 1, text: "text" })
```

**Edit**

As you point out though -- your example is using mutli-key, which is not supported when combined with a text index. Unfortunately, it's a limitation of MongoDB.

Comment: Great, thanks. I couldn't find in the documentation an explicit statement that index intersection does not work with text indexes but your answer clarifies that

Comment: Wait. The page you mentioned says: "A compound text index cannot include any other special index types, such as multi-key or geospatial index fields." So `db.col.ensureIndex({"concepts.name": 1, text: "text" })` is not allowed since "concepts.name" is a multi-key index, right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I didn't spot the fact that you were using a multi-key when I looked at your example (my head said sub-object with `{` and `}` rather than array of objects).